# expectation in coin draw problem

Tags: probability

I've been stuck on this question for a while. Two coins are selected at random from $3$ pennies, $2$ nickels, and $1$ dime with no replacement, and $X$ is the sum of the two coins. What is the probability function and the expected value?

My solution: For probability function for $X$,

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac36\cdot\frac25,&\text{for }X=2\text{ cents}\\\\
\frac26\cdot\frac25,&\text{for }X=6\text{ cents}\\\\
\frac36\cdot\frac15,&\text{for }X=11\text{ cents}\\\\
\frac36\cdot\frac15,&\text{for }X=10\text{ cents}\\\\
\frac16\cdot\frac35,&\text{for }X=15\text{ cents}\;.
\end{cases}$$

I can not seem to get a reasonable solution for $\mathrm{E}X$, because $\mathrm{E}X$ is a mean value where each value that $X$ takes on is either $2, 6, 10, 11$, or $15$ cents. I can't spend any more time on this, it's driving me nuts. Thanks!

Comment: Your $f(x)$ can’t be right: the probabilities sum to only $19/30$.

Answer (score 4):

You are thinking in the right direction, but if you check, your probabilities don't add to $1$.  For 11 cents, $\frac 36 \cdot \frac 15$ is the chance you take a penny and then a dime, but you can also take the dime first, so it needs to be doubled.  For 15, you need a dime and a nickel, but in either order, so $2\cdot \frac 16 \cdot \frac 25$.  10 cents is wrong differently.  Then EX is just $\sum P(X)X$, so $2P(2)+6P(6)+\ldots$

Comment: Got it.. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The following solution is **not** the one you are expected to produce at this stage. I am mentioning it in order to provide some information that may be useful later. Assume we are picking the coins one at a time.

Let $X_1$ be the value of your first pick, and let $X_2$ be the value of your second pick. Then $X=X_1+X_2$.  By the *linearity of expectation*, we have
$$E(X)=E(X_1+X_2)=E(X_1)+E(X_2).$$
Note that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are not independent, but that doesn't matter.

We have
$$E(X_1)=1\cdot \frac{3}{6}+5\cdot\frac{2}{6}+10\cdot\frac{1}{6}=\frac{23}{6}.$$
Exactly the same calculation shows that $E(X_2)=\dfrac{23}{6}$.  (The probabilities for the various coins are the same for the second pick as for the first.)

It follows that $E(X)=\dfrac{46}{6}$.